# add_dependencies for dependencies that have non-zero exit code

Tags: cmake

I am doing this:

```
    add_custom_target(Target1
        COMMAND Command1
    )
    add_custom_target(Target2
        COMMAND Command2
    )
    add_dependencies(Target2 Target1)
```

but if `Command1` has a non-zero exit code, `Command2` is never run. Is there a way to make sure that `Target2` runs after `Target1`, but no matter what the exit code of `Command1` is?

Comment: you can always execute some simple statement at the end of the command so it would reuturn 0 exit code(like echo, for example)

Comment: @DavideSpataro I just want a sequential ordering (Target1 must be run before Target2) - I don't want Target2 to depend on Target1 succeeding.

Comment: @ixSci But the add_custom_target ends immediately as soon as one of the COMMANDs returns non-zero, right? So the second COMMAND of 'echo' would never be reached.

Comment: I mean do it as part of the first command you can do a few command as one by piping them. So it should not see any return value untill all the commands are complete

Comment: Or you can put the commands, with echo as the last one, in some script file and invoke it in the COMMAND

Comment: @ixSci I tried this: `        add_custom_target(Target1
            COMMAND ctest | echo "echoing"
        )` but it just echos and does not run 'ctest'.

Comment: hm, what about  `add_custom_target(Target1 COMMAND ctest COMMAND echo "echoing" )`, won't help?

Comment: @ixSci Nope, the first COMMAND fails and the second is never run.

Comment: The solution here looks reasonable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322547/catch-return-value-in-cmake-add-custom-command

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
    file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/NoExitCodeTests.cmake "execute_process(COMMAND ctest)")

    add_custom_target(Target1
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P NoExitCodeTests.cmake
    )
```

This will make Target1 always return 0 no matter what happens in `ctest`. Ugly, but sometimes CMake is ugly :)