# How can I ignore errors on an individual CMake command in my CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

I have a project where the `CMakeLists.txt` attempts to read a file which may or may not be present.  It is not a problem for the file to be missing and the script handles either case.  This is used to tweak the compilation environment slightly if we can detect a known Linux distribution:

```
file (READ /etc/redhat-release RHREL)
if (RHREL MATCHES "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6*")
   # tweak for RHEL6
elseif (RHREL MATCHES "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7*")
   # tweak for RHEL7
else()
   # either read failed, or we didn't match a known RHEL release
   # fallback to reasonable defaults
endif()
```

The problem is that when `file(READ...)` fails it seems to be outputting a message using the `SEND_ERROR` parameter.  This means that my configuration continues into the catch-all `else()` as I expect, but at the end of configuration `CMake` refuses to generate a `Makefile`.

How can I run `file(READ)` in such a way that I can cope with errors locally and prevent them from failing the entire configuration?

Comment: You could also check [`CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM.html) global variable. I don't think you actually need to read the `redhat-release` file.

Comment: Great idea.  I'll change to doing that - but I'd still love to know how to explicitly ignore an error on a command (not just `file(...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

In this special case, you could also check [`CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM.html).

The more general answer is you have to move your code into an external CMake script and call it with the all mighty [`execute_process()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command:

**FileDumpRedHatRelease.cmake**

```
file(READ /etc/redhat-release RHREL)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "${RHREL}")

# or if you don't mind the '-- ' leading dashes with STATUS messages
# (because normal CMake messages go to stderr)
#message(STATUS "${RHREL}")
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
execute_process( 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FileDumpRedHatRelease.cmake"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE RHREL
    ERROR_QUIET
)
```

**References**

Even those references are all discussing an `add_custom_command()` command that could fail, you can see the usage of `execute_process()` and external CMake scripts in such cases:

- [catch return value in CMake add_custom_command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322547/catch-return-value-in-cmake-add-custom-command)
- [CMake: Ignoring return codes on ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (hhc.exe)](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-October/017111.html)
- [0013146: ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND has no OUTPUT / RESULT Variable](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13146)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the file exists first (n.b. if it exists but isn't readable you will still have a problem):

```
if (EXISTS /etc/redhat-release)
```